# how to make .join('') in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code isn't working, I guess it's because .join('') doesn't work in jquery but I can't find any solution that seems legit. Thanks for your help. If needed I can show what I have in my html file:

```
        <form id="img_search">
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
            <output id="list"></output>
        </form>
```

js code:

```
$( "#files" ).bind('change', function() { 
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
        }

        $("#list").html('<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>');    
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't do anything to `Array.prototype.join`

Comment: Try using + when concatenating the string in the `.push()` instead of a .

Comment: @MrHunter I don't see the `.` that you're talking about.

Comment: add a `console.log(output)` after your for loop and see what your array looks like.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, I meant to type a , instead of a .

My bad

Comment: Is your forloop in an infinite loop? Once you get past all the files, `files[i]` will just be `undefined` and the loop will continue onto infinity, no? I'm thinking perhaps you need a `i < files.length` in your loop declaration.

Comment: @MrHunter `Array.prototype.push` can take multiple items to push just fine. There's nothing wrong with this code. It's mostly copied from HTML5rocks.com, save the jQuery. @Brian has the answer.

Comment: `.join()` has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: @buley I disagree. `bind` in 2014? What's `evt`?

Comment: @tomaroo `undefined` is falsey, so it will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event to the callback - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecr2u3bf/)

```
$( "#files" ).bind('change', function(event) { 
       var files = event.target.files; 
});
```

Comment: This is indeed the problem with his or her copy paste. Missing the event argument.

Comment: You could also use `this.files`, since jQuery always binds `this` to the target in its event handlers.

Comment: No. I'm using firefox

Comment: Your code works just fine for me :), wasn't a join issue.. you just weren't setting `files` because the event parameter of the callback wasn't set.

Comment: Yes, it's being loaded with $(document).ready() I still can't understand why isn't working. I have in two different files, one with js code and other with the html code, if I put the code in <script></script> works just fine but I wanted it organized and I'm loading the javascript to the html

Comment: And I also have other functions in the js code that works just fine, this is the only thing that isn't working

Comment: Still nothing and I also tried making a function and calling this way $( "#files" ).change(handleFileSelect(event));

Comment: Since this solved the question above, mark it as correct and ask another question regarding why your code isn't firing correctly when in an external file. Be sure to paste all code in the file because it may be causing conflicts I otherwise would not be able to see